# Getting Null while converting NSString from NSMutableData?

Tags: ios, stream, metadata

I guess it would be a duplicate, In metaData I am getting "Live365" Stream metadata, but still I am asking I am getting `null` if I am using

```
NSLog(@"SONG META :%@", [[NSString alloc] 
       initWithData:metaData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

and it's printing ASCII values if I am using

```
NSLog(@"SONG META :%@", [[NSString alloc] 
         initWithData:metaData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

I have tried below schemes but getting null:

```
   NSUTF8StringEncoding
   NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding
   NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding
   NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding
   NSUTF32StringEncoding
```

Comment: check correct encoding schemes.

Comment: which scheme i should use becoz if i am using "NSUTF8StringEncoding" it's giving me null.Please explain a little.

Comment: by the scheme you saved your metaData, if you are not sure, try checking by each one.

Comment: I tried others it's giving me null too. I want to know that is something wrong with the metadata which i am getting from response.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your `NSMutableData` object is indeed complete. If you download it from a web service you should only alloc-init the string after the download has finished.

If it is a valid string, your method should work fine.

If not, it is not a valid string and the results is expected.

Comment: but same code is working for ShoutCast and ICEcast Stream. my object is complete.Can we test the the NSMutable Data that it having valid string or not?